# Share folder with only one pc over the network

Tags: networking, windows-10, shared-folders

This is the problem I want to solve:

I have 3 Windows 10 PCs in a domestic network, say `PC1`, `PC2` and `PC3`.

On each machine there is one and only one user: `User1` on `PC1`, `User2` on `PC2` and `User3` on `PC3`. All are admins of their respectives machines, without any passwords.

On `PC1` I have a folder `C:\Folder`. I want to share (read and write) `C:\Folder` with `User2` (`User1` also has access, but `User3` should not). How can this be done?

I have only been able to give permission to all users. A step by step guide would be of most help. Thank you.

Comment: If you create the `User2` account on the `PC1` machine (without admin privileges), it should be relatively easy to adjust your permissions to that shared folder.

Comment: @Run5k Would it be a problem if `User2` and `User3` actually have the same name?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that it would.  It will allow `User3` to have the same access to the share that `User2` has.  It sounds like you originally configured this network so that it was very "user friendly," but that concept becomes problematic when you try to do something more advanced like you are now.